# I have a code and it's not accept where I have to run it

Tags: html

I need to write the correct CSS, but I think I am not doing it right.

Each `.item` in the `.menu` DIV should have a `40%` width, `0.4em` padding and margin, a solid white `1px` border, an `inline-block` display, and the cursor should change into a pointing hand when it is over it.

```
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <p class="mdc-typography--headline6"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <p class="mdc-typography--headline6"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <p class="mdc-typography--headline6"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <p class="mdc-typography--headline6"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

this where the problem come in

```
.item{
    width:40%;
    padding:0.4em;
    margin:0.4em;
    border:1px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
   }
```

Comment: What's the current behavior of the CSS?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Gradr tells me i have not formatted the css code as instructed

Comment: "Style the '.item' DIVs as specified in the instructions" @ ladygremlin

Comment: If the instructions are specifically "each .item in the .menu", then change `.item` to `.menu .item` in the css. The rest looks OK.

Comment: Also, since this is homework, be aware that this HTML won't pass the W3C validator, which may or may not be a big deal to your grader.

Comment: your code is getting full css as you have written here. whats you expected outcome from here

Comment: I expect it to be accepted via gradr thou. Its not , :( can if u can twick it a little bit thanks @Irin

Comment: I guess you didnot understand what he said properly. what you have written you did it exactly here. please be sure about the requirement first.